# Showing the Progress of a Background Task

Tags: java, javafx-8

Hi i want to show the progress of a background task.

```
@FXML
    private void addOfficeBarrierSelect() {
        App.getInstance().showProgressIndicator(myController);
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                ScreensController colllectScreenController = new ScreensController();
                colllectScreenController.loadScreen(Screens.ADD_OFFICE_BARRIER);
                colllectScreenController.setScreen(Screens.ADD_OFFICE_BARRIER);
                content.setContent(null);
                content.setContent(colllectScreenController);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                App.getInstance().hideProgressIndicator(myController);
            }

            @Override
            protected void failed() {
                super.failed();
                App.getInstance().hideProgressIndicator(myController);
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```

And below code is the progress popup i have used in my application.

```
public void showProgressIndicator(ScreensController myController) {
        myController.setDisable(true);
        if (popupProgressIndicator == null) {
            JFXSpinner spinner = new JFXSpinner();
            spinner.setLayoutX(0);
            spinner.setLayoutY(0);
            spinner.setPrefHeight(200);
            spinner.setPrefWidth(200);
            popupProgressIndicator = new Popup();
            popupProgressIndicator.getContent().add(spinner);
        }
        if (!popupProgressIndicator.isShowing()) {
            popupProgressIndicator.show(primaryStage);
            popupProgressIndicator.centerOnScreen();
        }
    }
public void hideProgressIndicator(ScreensController myController) {
        myController.setDisable(false);
        if (popupProgressIndicator.isShowing())
            popupProgressIndicator.hide();
    }
```

The problem is when i run the app , No FX app thread exception occuring..

`Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-6` and pointing at void call() method inside Task thread.
Is there any solution for it..

`James_D` solution Actually works for me.But i got to change the code to this.

```
showProgressIndicator(myController);
Task<FXMLLoader> task = new Task<FXMLLoader>() {
            @Override
            protected FXMLLoader call() throws Exception {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(Screens.ADD_MEMBER));
                return loader;
            }
            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                super.succeeded();
                hideProgressIndicator(myController);
            }
            @Override
            protected void failed() {
                super.failed();
    hideProgressIndicator(myController);
            }
        };
new Thread(task).start();
```

After changing the code again progress not showing.just followed @james_D anwser.

Comment: You shouldn't be changing anything in the UI via the background task. The background task needs to do its thing and report state changes back to the UI, so that the UI can update itself.

Comment: Yah i  get it..What change you suggesting for my above code.

Comment: There's various ways of doing this TBH. You could have a timer running on the UI continually checking for state changes. For instance, you could have a postState() method in your UI, which accepts a state object from your background process. Your background process can then post state to the UI. The UI timer can then tick and check for messages in its message queue of state objects from the postState() method. And then simply process whatever is in its queue. There's several ways of managing this, but this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: i have added the Platform.runLater inside void call() and inside that i have added ui operation.Now the exception not showing anymore.But the app hang up for some time and progress is not showing.

Comment: Yeah, that's not necessarily going to update when you want it to. Better to manage the updates yourself in a controlled fashion via a timed task. You could use an AnimationTimer on the UI side to continually check for state changes. And simply let your background task post its progress to the UI. Then the UI can update accordingly based on the state change.

Comment: Could you please share the code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113063/discussion-between-boycod3-and-manodestra).

Comment: Your updated code doesn't make sense. The only thing you do in the background thread is create the `FXMLLoader`. That is not an operation that takes any appreciable time at all, so there is no need to have a background thread for it. Perhaps you need to explain why you are wanting a background task in the first place.

Comment: Controller initializable method contains db operation.so I want to suppress the time delay .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you are updating the UI from a background thread. You need to update the UI from the FX Application Thread. You can do this with a call to `Platform.runLater()` if you need to make incremental updates during your `call()` method execution, or (as it seems in this case: I'm not sure exactly what the `loadScreen` and `setScreen` methods do, but I am assuming they do not change the existing scene graph) if you only need to update the UI once the task is complete, update the UI in the `succeeded` method of the task:

```
@FXML
private void addOfficeBarrierSelect() {
    App.getInstance().showProgressIndicator(myController);
    Task<ScreensController> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected ScreensController call() throws Exception {
            ScreensController colllectScreenController = new ScreensController();
            colllectScreenController.loadScreen(Screens.ADD_OFFICE_BARRIER);
            colllectScreenController.setScreen(Screens.ADD_OFFICE_BARRIER);
            return colllectScreenController;
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            super.succeeded();
            content.setContent(getValue());
            App.getInstance().hideProgressIndicator(myController);
        }

        @Override
        protected void failed() {
            super.failed();
            App.getInstance().hideProgressIndicator(myController);
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple example to illustrate how it could be done, using an AnimationTimer and some state (busy and labelText). The state of the button and the label are amended on every tick of the animation timer. And the task is the thing that updates the state (NOT the UI).

The state here would require to be synchronized, of course, so you'd perhaps wish to implement a postMessage() method that would allow the task to report state back to the UI, which would then add to a message queue, which would then in turn be consumed by the AnimationTimer. However, the code provided below is for **ILLUSTRATIVE PURPOSES ONLY**. The point is to highlight that **you cannot update UI controls from a non-UI thread**.

I've also added a ProgressBar and bound its progressProperty to the progressProperty of the task. So, there's TWO ways of managing updates for you :)

Using progressProperty() binding is probably the best here. No need for the AnimationTimer in that instance. But, if you do implement that way of doing it, then you should implement a message queue on the UI thread and synchronize state change via a postMessage() method.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Progress extends Application {
    String labelText = "Foobar";
    boolean busy = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
        progress.setProgress(0);
        Button button = new Button("Test");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Button has been pressed...");
                Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        busy = true;
                        System.out.println("Calling long running task...");
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                            labelText = "Progress: " + i;
                            updateProgress(i, 100);
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void succeeded() {
                        System.out.println("Succeeded");
                        busy = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void failed() {
                        System.out.println("Failed");
                    }
                };

                progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
                Thread thread = new Thread(task);
                thread.start();
            }
        });

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                label.setText(labelText);
                button.setDisable(busy);
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        VBox vbox = new VBox(label, progress, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 300);
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

NB the task must do nothing with controls, only state.

See also here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

And this SO question: [JavaFX : How to pass value from background thread to JavaFX UI thread with Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342968/javafx-how-to-pass-value-from-background-thread-to-javafx-ui-thread-with-task).

Comment: What's the point of the `AnimationTimer`? Why not just update the label directly from `Platform.runLater()`? Also, you are accessing variables (`labelText` and `busy`) from two different threads, so you need to properly synchronize access to them.

Comment: I wouldn't personally, as you can't guarantee when Platform.runLater() is run. You don't need the AnimationTimer, if you bind the property from your task to your progressbar. I only used the AnimationTimer to illustrate that you handle your UI updates on the UI thread and state only in your tasks, passing the state changes from task to UI and letting the UI update itself. At the moment, you're using the task to update UI controls from a thread other than the UI thread and that's why it's failing.

Comment: (Not my question: I just object to incorrect answers on here.) But `Platform.runLater()` also schedules the update on the UI thread. It is just as "guaranteed" as the `AnimationTimer`'s `handle(...)` method, which will run on each frame: you have no "guarantee" as to when a frame will be rendered. And you need to fix the threading issues with your variables.

Comment: You don't have to use the AnimationTimer technique, like I said. You should simply bind the progressProperty of the task to your control and update the progress inside your task. The principle remains the same though. You only update state within external threads and post messages (in some prescribed fashion) to the UI thread, so that it can then handle how it updates itself. I could easily have implemented the postMessage() method I mentioned above and added a message queue to process via the AnimationTimer. That technique was not a full solution, but to illustrate the principle involved.

Comment: Both techniques are illustrated within the answer. The progressProperty() one is obviously preferable. The AnimationTimer is to illustrate the point, so that you can see how to allow the UI to update itself.

Comment: But it is broken. You are sharing state between threads without proper synchronization.

Comment: The binding of progressProperty() is not broken in the slightest. The AnimationTimer technique was merely to illustrate the division of concerns. I could have made it more thread safe by adding the message queue, as I said, but I didn't do that above, as you wanted me to provide you with an answer. I made the assumption that you would understand what I was trying to illustrate and be able to implement a fuller solution on your own. A message queue would be thread safe, but I didn't include that here, as the AnimationTimer was only to illustrate the principle of UI/state division. Make sense?

Comment: And as i said above, the issue is that you're trying to update the UI from a non UI thread. That's your issue here. And the solution has been given in two fashions, binding of properties, or using a message queue that the external thread can post to via a simple API on the UI thread (not fully implemented as part of the answer, given the illustrative nature of the answer).

Comment: Again, not my question. But look: you are accessing state (`labelText` and `busy`) from two different threads **with no synchronization**. There is no guarantee the FX Application Thread will *ever* see the changes made to those variables from the background thread unless you synchronize access to them. This has nothing to do with JavaFX, it is basic multithreading in Java.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of "illustrative purposes" you're missing here. It was to illustrate the division of UI and state between UI thread and non UI thread. UI operations on UI thread only, state on non UI thread only and passed to UI via a well defined thread-safe mechanism e.g. message queue. The progressProperty() method is your best bet and I stated that clearly in the answer.

Comment: How can you illustrate anything about multithreading with code that is broken from a threading perspective? **You cannot share state between threads unless you synchronize access to it,** or at least mark that state as volatile.

Comment: Yes, and posting to the UI via a method that then adds to a message queue on the UI, processed via a timer, handles that. Didn't put that in the answer, as the AnimationTimer was to illustrate how to correct your error and divide the concerns. I KNOW it's not thread-safe. ILLUSTRATIVE PURPOSES ONLY. Or use progressProperty() as suggested. There's no disagreement here, so I'm not sure why you seem to be arguing over it.

Comment: I'm arguing about it because your code is wrong - potentially fatally wrong. There is a disagreement here: you think your code is correct. It is not correct.

Comment: Yes, and I'm fully aware of that. We both are. It was to illustrate that your code was trying to access UI controls from a non UI thread. And I gave an admittedly non thread safe way to do that, but I had already qualified in my initial comments to do it via a message queue. I had thought you would have understood that I already understood that.